# How to add an item to a TabPanel in a Panel with Sencha Touch 1?

Tags: pointers, sencha-touch, viewport, tabpanel

I have the following code, which generates a basic layout for my app:

```
tabpanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    fullscreen: false,
    ui        : 'dark',
    sortable  : false,
    tabBarDock: 'bottom',
    cardSwitchAnimation: 'flip',
    items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html : '1',
            cls  : 'card1',
            icon : 'tab1'
    }]
});

lists.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: "top",
        title: 'title'
    }],
    items: [tabpanel],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.tabpanel.add(new lists.views.ItemLists());
        lists.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    },
});
```

This doesn't work, probably due to the fact that the TabPanel that is inside the Viewport Panel cannot be pointed to like this. I've searched through the sencha documentation but I can't find how to add the

> new lists.views.ItemLists()

to the tabpanel, which in turn is inside the

> lists.views.Viewport

Also, there will be other stuff I want to declare before my viewport (or even after it) that I want to add to specific other panels I might add later. What is the best way to achieve this?

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the `this.` off the reference to the `tabpanel` in the Viewport's `initComponent` method then it should work because the `tabpanel` variable is global.

Alternatively, you can access the Viewport's items via the `items` property, for example,

```
initComponent: function(){
    this.items.get(0).add(new lists.views.ItemLists());

    lists.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Hope this helps

Stuart